# Django Management Command Generating Model Entries Corrupts File if File Is the Same on Each Entry

Tags: django

I have a custom management command in Django that generates an email to be added to the "django-mail-queue" app MailerMessage model. This tool reads from an existing table for information. However I am having issues with attachments where the first one, the attachment is fine, but the second one the attachment is corrupted. My belief is that Django is queuing up all the SQL commands and executing them all at once and thus reading the attachment file all at the same time for every entry. I think this is causing a race condition that is corrupting the second attachment.

This is the code

```
for send_to_user in send_to_users:
    msg = MailerMessage()
    msg.subject = campaign.subject
    msg.from_address = from_address
    msg.to_address = send_to_user.email
    msg.html_content = f"some content"

    # ATTACH THE ATTACHMENTS
    if attachments:
        for attachment in attachments:
            msg.add_attachment(attachment=attachment.file_attachment)

    msg.save()
```

The attachments is a model of this that gets iterated over in the above code to then create the attachment for the individual email going out:

```
class CampaignAttachments(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, related_name="attachments")
    file_attachment = ProtectedFileField(upload_to=upload_attachment_to, blank=True, max_length=1024, unique=True)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=1024, blank=True, null=True)
```

How do I get it to save directly without causing this race condition? Shouldn't msg.save() save to the database right away at the end of the for loop and then process the next one?

Comment: What is `attachments`?

Comment: An attachment would be any file, whether PDF, Image, TXT file, etc.

Comment: No, I mean, literally what is `attachments` here? An iterable of... what?

Comment: Updated description to include attachments model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you are calling `read()` on the same open file multiple times causing the later calls to read to not be useful because after the first call to read the pointer is already at the end of the file. This call to `read()` is present in the following [line [Source code - GitHub]](https://github.com/Privex/django-mail-queue/blob/b566ec4438ebb5ce4585220936eedc6130b9f07a/mailqueue/models.py#L72) of the method `add_attachment` of `MailerMessage`:

> ```
> file_content = ContentFile(attachment.read())
> ```

How to solve this? You need to call the `seek` (or simply `open` method on the file field would also work) method to update the pointer to the start of the file. So your loop should look something like:

```py
for attachment in attachments:
    attachment.file_attachment.open()
    msg.add_attachment(attachment=attachment.file_attachment)
```

Comment: I was starting to drill down into the backend of django-mailer-queue and Django and yes, I did find that when it started passing in the contents of the file that it wasn't getting the contents on the second one. I did what you suggested with the `attachment.file_attachement.open()` and that worked exactly as required. Thank you!